# Android HTTP POST - 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: android, apache, http

I am using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ library to interact with web server.

I am sending POST request and getting empty response with 200 status code (Ok).

But after inspecting connection with Fiddler I found I am getting 400 BAD REQUEST error

If I try GET request - everything goes alright

**UPD: I found problem source - my base64 parameter("data") is somehow changed. My code makes valid base64 string but in request  "0%3D%0A" is added making it unvalidateble**

My POST request:

```
POST http://example.com HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 143
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: android-async-http/1.4.1 (http://loopj.com/android-async-http)
Accept-Encoding: gzip

hash=123&data=123
```

My response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Android code:

```
public class RestClient {
     private static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.com";

      private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

      public static void post(RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
          client.post(BASE_URL, params, responseHandler);

      }


}
```

and

```
public static void register(String login, String email, String password,
            final RegisterProcessListener listener) {

        String base64 = Cryptography
                .credentialsToBase64(login, email, password);
        String md5 = Cryptography.Base64toMD5(base64);
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put(DATA, base64);
        params.put(HASH, md5);

        RestClient.post(...)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Where is your code that does the actual request, and where is it handled incorrectly?

Comment: actual request happens at RestClient.post

Comment: How did you manage to print-out your http request (like you've indicated in "My POST request") in plain text?